# CouchDB How to make queries with multiple complex keys

Tags: java, key, couchdb, view, nosql

I am trying to make a CouchDB view to obtain some document that is in set 1 and in set 2. For example, when I have a single key I can make some query like:

```
dbname/_design_doc/viewName?keys=[value1, value2, value3]
```

and it returns all the documents where it finds either the value1, 2 or 3. What I want is something like this but for a complex key.
For example,

```
dbname/_design_doc/viewName?keys=[[key1, key12, key13],[key21, key22]]
```

where key1x is a value for the first key and key2x is a value for the second key, meaning I would like to get every document that has key11 and key21, key11 and key22, key12 and key21, key12 and key22 and so on.

My view is this one:

```
"twokeys": {
      "map": "function(doc) {\n  if (doc.uid && doc.hid){\n        
                   emit([doc.uid, doc.hid], doc);\n  }\n}"
 }
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the answer is : Yes :)

Comment: Really @AlexisCôté ? I am trying to do it but I can't in JAVA code using ektorp. The keys parameter of ektorp asks for a Collection<?> and I can't create a collection of a vector<string>, vector<integer> because one of the keys is string and the other is integer, forgot about that part, sorry.

Comment: Then this might be a limitation of your library, imma take a look into it later.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409193/couchdb-map-reduce-view-query-from-ektorp)

Comment: I will try to do it tomorrow @AlexisCôté and get back to you! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem sir!

Comment: Hey @AlexisCôté ! So, I was able to do it! But now I was trying to filter by a date and it says that keys is not compatible with startKey or endKey. Guess that is not possible right?

Comment: You need to either use one or the other. If you want to query 2 static field and another range more dynamically with a range, you can have a range like this : startkey=[1,2,4]&endkey[1,2,6].

Comment: Yes that one I know @AlexisCôté , but the problem is I want to query the same that I've asked here but in some range of a third key. For example: all documents that are in set1 and set2 of keys and the date is between X and Y. I think it is impossible for couchdb. It doesn't let me use keys with startkey and endkey. I was trying to put everything in startKey like:


    startKey=[ ["key11", "key12"], ["key21","key22"] ,"date" ]

Comment: Indeed, you can't use multiple keys with the startkey. In this case, you need to figure out what will be the most efficient way to fetch your data. Multiple queries(If network operations is not a problem, this could be doable if you don't have a lot of keys sets), fetch by the keys then filter locally with the date range, or fetch by range and then filter by the keys.

Comment: Yes, that was what I did. Well, thank you very much @AlexisCôté ! If you can answer the question with the link I can mark it as an answer maybe?

Best regards m8

Answer (score 0):

1. You can query with the **keys** parameter using complex keys if you follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409193/couchdb-map-reduce-view-query-from-ektorp).
2. Unfortunately, you can't query both the startkey or the endkey with the keys.